# Memory leak issue using PyTorch IterableDataset with zarr

Tags: pytorch, zarr

I'm trying to build a `pytorch` project on an `IterableDataset` with `zarr` as storage backend.

```py
class Data(IterableDataset):
    def __init__(self, path, start=None, end=None):
        super(Data, self).__init__()
        store = zarr.DirectoryStore(path)
        self.array = zarr.open(store, mode='r')

        if start is None:
            start = 0
        if end is None:
            end = self.array.shape[0]

        assert end > start

        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def __iter__(self):
        return islice(self.array, self.start, self.end)
```

This works quite nicely with small test-datasets but once i move to my actual dataset (480 000 000 x 290) i'm running into a memory leak. I've tried logging out the python heap periodically as everything slows to a crawl, but i couldn't see anything increasing in size abnormally, so the lib i used (`pympler`) didn't actually catch the memory leak.

I'm kind of at my wits end, so if anybody has any idea how to further debug this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Cross-posted on [PyTorch Forums](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/iterable-dataset-with-zarr-as-storage-backend-results-in-degrading-performance/91100).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I had an issue in my validation routine:

```py
with torch.no_grad():
    for batch in tqdm(testloader, **params):
        x = batch[:, 1:].to(device)
        y = batch[:, 0].unsqueeze(0).T
        y_test_pred = torch.sigmoid(sxnet(x))
        y_pred_tag = torch.round(y_test_pred)
        y_pred_list.append(y_pred_tag.cpu().numpy())
        y_list.append(y.numpy())
```

I originally thought that I am well clear of running into troubles with appending my results to lists, but the issue is that the result of `.numpy` was an array of arrays (since the original datatype was a 1xn Tensor).

Adding `.flatten()` on the numpy arrays has fixed this issue and the RAM consumption is now as I originally provisioned.

Comment: Hi, I am doing similar thing and got similar issue but I am new to pytorch. Can you be show me specifically where to add the `.flatten()`? Thanks!

Comment: @LouisYang `y_pred_list.append(y_pred_tag.cpu().numpy().flatten())` and `y_list.append(y.numpy().flatten())`